# Providing seperate ref attribute to multiple element in reacJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I am trying to build a simple to-do list where each task can be edited by clicking on edit button which shows a previously hidden text field in which user can enter new name for the current task, for this I need to assign a ref value to each task so far I have tried

```
   let refrences = useRef([]);               
   //this is within a array.map method
   <input type='text' ref={refrences.current[index]}  /> 
   //some code here
```

But refrences.current[index] always shows as undefined and I have no idea why that's the case but when I try the following(found it online)

```
   let refrences = useRef([]);  
   //this is within a array.map method                  
   <input type='text' ref={element => refrences.current[index]=element}  /> 
   //some code here
```

This works perfectly fine but I have no idea why this works. I know this is an arrow function but I can't tell what the 'element' stands for even though it has not been defined anywhere else. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works perfectly fine but I have no idea why this works.

To the best of my knowledge you can pass at least two kinds of values to the `ref` pop:

1. A "reference object" returned by `useRef` [<sup>React Docs</sup>](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)
2. A function [<sup>React Docs</sup>](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback)

### Reference object

As you already know, `useRef` returns an object with a `current` property. When you pass that object to the `ref` prop, React can assign the DOM element to that property, i.e. something like

```
ref.current = element
```

(to be honest I don't know if React requires the `current` property to be present. It might as well always assign to the `current` property if the passed value is an object)

### Function

If you pass a function however, React will call that function with the DOM element passed as argument, something like:

```
ref(element)
```

> I can't tell what the 'element' stands for even though it has not been defined anywhere else.

In your code `element` is a parameter of the function you pass to `ref`. It works like any other (callback) function. The caller of the function, in this case React, will provide a value for that argument.
It's essentially the same as for example `Array#forEach` and other higher level functions:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(i => console.log(i))
```

In this example you pass a function to `forEach` that has a single parameter `i`. The JavaScript engine will call that function for every element in the array and pass that element to the function (which therefore gets assigned to the parameter `i`).

---

### Why does `ref={refrences.current[index]}` not work?

The value of `reference.current[index]` is not a "reference object". It's not an object with a `current` property, so React cannot execute `ref.current = element`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Felix Kling, but when I declared 'refrences' I passed '[]' to useRef, shouldn't that return an array of with current property? from react.dev  : "useRef returns a ref object with a single current property initially set to the initial value you provided." so I guess I am missing something?

Comment: `useReg([])` will return `{current: []}`. Then you are passing `refrences.current[index]` to the `ref` prop, but `refrences.current[index]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do feel I need to study the subject further.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, known as "using callback refs"
by passing a callback to the ref, you get more granular control on binding a DOM element to the react ref object.
you provide a callback and your current element which you have added ref props on it will be pass as element argument by react,

so if you have an index, you know which position of reference array it should be placed and you also have a DOM reference using Element so you could capture it on your loop.